# How long do breadcrumbs last?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I'm currently trying to make a dish that calls for breadcrumbs, but the only ones I have expired on October 22 of 2019.  They are unopened and were kept in a cool dry place. It sounds stupid but are these still usable?

Answer (score 2):

If they're the dried bought type, they keep almost indefinitely so long as they stay dry (even open; I use them very slowly) . The date is about quality not safety.

As always, if there seems to be anything wrong, such as signs of dampness on the container (at least here they're packed in cardboard), be more cautious

Comment: Perhaps, but I can get two types here, fully well-known, branded from the supermarket in a posh carton, or 'fresh in a sealed bag', from the local 'deli' [but still a proper commercial product, not  in any way home-made]. The former has a year on it to start with, the latter only a month. the former looks like 'breadcrumbs', the latter like actual crumbs of bread.

Comment: @Tetsujin they may be bought, but I reckon the second type aren't dried, and therefore aren't what I'm talking about. They could be partially dried to get a month's shelf life but I haven't seen those myself. I normally freeze home made crumbs, but have tried drying them. If further crumbled (food processor) after drying in a cool oven they look a lot like the supermarket ones, and keep just as well